# magento 2 Infortis ultimo theme display category tree menu on the left of the search result page

Tags: magento2, layout, search, category-tree, ultimo

I am using the Infortis ultimo theme, in the included feature, i was able to add the category tree menu on the left bar of each category page, but how can i add it to the search result page?

is this something i can find using template hint & add to the layout file in `Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml` ?

the shortcode to add it to the CMS Page or Static Block is this, how do I use it to add to the search result page?

```
{{block class="Infortis\UltraMegamenu\Block\Navigation" template="categories.phtml" parent="X"
depth="X" block_name="X"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the category tree shows in the search result page by copying the `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` layout file to the ultimo theme folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
        <body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd"> 
        <!-- add category to left -->
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Infortis\UltraMegamenu\Block\Navigation" before="-" template="categories.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Since I was not able to assign the "parent" "depth" and "block_name" values in the XML file above. I then duplicate the "categories.phtml" and create a new template called "categories_searchresult.phtml" and assign the value of "parent" "depth" and "block_name" directly into the template file. Finally, change the template path in the xml to the new one.